# nslookup can not get service ip on latest busybox

Tags: docker, kubernetes, busybox

**Reproduce steps:**

1. `kubectl run busybox1 --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=busybox:1.28 -- sleep 3600`
2. `kubectl run busybox2 --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=busybox:1.31.1 -- sleep 3600`
3. `kubectl exec -ti busybox1 -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

**works fine**

> Server:    10.96.0.10
>
> Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
>
> Name:      kubernetes.default
>
> Address 1: 10.96.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local

4. `kubectl exec -ti busybox2 -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

**not working**

> Server:         10.96.0.10
>      Address:        10.96.0.10:53
>
> ** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN
>
> *** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer
>
> command terminated with exit code 1

does nslookup work differently on 1.31.1?

what's the correct way to use nslookup on 1.31.1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DNS inside busybox only works correctly in images <= 1.28.4.

Fixing the version `image: "busybox:1.28.0"` should do the trick.

There's a thread here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66924

Answer (score 0):

change to `alpine`, used

```
$ getent ahostsv4 kubernetes.default | awk '/STREAM/ {print $1;exit; }'
10.96.0.1
$ getent ahostsv4 kube-dns.kube-system | awk '/STREAM/ {print $1;exit; }'
10.96.0.10
```